# unable to pass a parameters to php in a form?

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I have the html form but i am unable to pass the hidden parameter to the next page.i want to pass the hidden clientid to the next page but i am unable to pass.

**My Form**

```
<form action = "clientpricelistexport/exp_to_excel.php" method = "post">

<input type="hidden" name="clientid" id="clientid" value="<?echo $clientid;?>" >

<table  id="CPH_GridView1">

    <tbody >
<?php   

  $dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
 $dbUsername = 'xxx';
 $dbPassword = 'xxxx';
  $dbDatabase = 'xxxx';
  $db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
  mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");
$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];
if($clientid!=""){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `clientid` , `clientname`
FROM `client_list`
WHERE `clientid` = '$clientid'");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo ' 
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientid" style="width:140px" class="edit clientid '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["clientid"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientname" style="width:160px" class="edit clientname '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["clientname"].'</td>      

                <td style="width:65px" class="deleteclientlist '.$rows["id"].'"></td>

        </tr>';


}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Export"  class="export">

   </form>
```

and i am try to print it in next page like this.

```
$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];
print $clientid;
```

but it not printing anyone tell me where i am going wrong thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `<form action = "exp_to_excel.php" method = "post">`
as method "POST" but accessing the values with "GET"

try

```
$clientid=$_POST['clientid'];
print $clientid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using method="POST". To retrieve data from a form using this method you have to use:

```
$clientid = $_POST['clientid']
```

([$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php))

or

```
$clientid = $_REQUEST['clientid']
```

([$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php))

Answer (score 0):

User $_REQUEST['clientid'], it will handle both get and post request.

Answer (score 0):

you specify the method post in your form and get it from the $_GET.
Change it to

```
$clientid=$_POST['clientid'];
```